# Values for 240dpi screen

Tags: android, size, screen, dpi, dimensions

i want to create a folder values, only for 240dpi screens, and if it is bigger that that so use other folder like 480..

The "values-sw240dp" folder is not working to me.

My main goal is to set different dimens values for 240dpi screens.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong folder names.

Dpi densities qualifiers have following values

```
ldpi (low) ~120dpi
mdpi (medium) ~160dpi
hdpi (high) ~240dpi
xhdpi (extra-high) ~320dpi
xxhdpi (extra-extra-high) ~480dpi
xxxhdpi (extra-extra-extra-high) ~640dpi
```

You should name your folder `values-hdpi`

[Using configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

`values-sw240dp` means screen smallest width is 240dp